# Proton gas density

Tags: electrostatics, density, protons

As far as I know the lightest gas is hydrogen due to low mass of its nucleus, but what if we were to somehow strip hydrogen atoms of electrons and enclose protons in a container made of teflon (high electronegativity).

Would such a proton-only gas be stable? And what would be its density under atmospheric pressure (assume teflon envelope around the gas)? Would electrostatic effects between positively charged protons contribute to lowering density of such gas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lightest gas that is stable at room temperatue is $H_2$ (two hydrogen atoms bonded to each other).

At very high temperature and/or low pressure, the hydrogen molecule dissociates to become atomic hydrogen.

At even higher temperature, the hydrogen ionizes.  The electron is no longer bound to the proton.  This is a plasma state.  Electrons and protons are still both present.

If just bare protons were present, they would react with the teflon.

See [this](http://www.wag.caltech.edu/home/jsu/Thesis/node31.html) for more information on states of hydrogen.

Comment: Is there any molecule that would not react with a proton?

Comment: I think any neutral molecule or atom would react with a bare proton.  Even helium (He) reacts to form HeH+.